# Chart.js Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

Quiero hacer algunas pruebas con la libreria chart.js, añado la libreria manualmente a mi proyecto (sin usar bower).

He consultado [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176769/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-chart-js) pregunta en el foro Ingles pero actualmente no esta la carpeta `dist`en la descarga de [github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) de la libreria.

He probado ha descargar los archivos Chart.bundle.min.js y Chart.bundle.js por separado desde [aqui](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js) pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar.

Por ultimo he probado con otras de las respuestas, que es [descargar](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) require.js y sigue igual. Simpre el mismo error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at chart.js:4

Lo que se encuentra en esta linea es lo siguiente:

```
var Chart = require('./core/core.js')();
```

Por ultimo incluyo mi codigo, creo que es irrelevante pero nunca viene mal un poco mas de informacion.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba 1</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chart/src/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chart/src/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>  
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chart/src/chart.js"></script>             
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="chart/src/require.js"></script>               

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="linegraph" style="height:400px;width:600px"></div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                Chart.plugins.register({
                beforeDraw: function(chart, easing) {
                var chartArea = chart.chartArea;
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

                // Replace these IDs if you have given your axes IDs in the config
                var xScale = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
                var yScale = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];

                var midX = xScale.getPixelForValue(0);
                var midY = yScale.getPixelForValue(0);

                // Top left quadrant
                ctx.fillStyle = window.chartColors.red;
                ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, chartArea.top, midX - chartArea.left, midY - chartArea.top);

                // Top right quadrant
                ctx.fillStyle = window.chartColors.blue;
                ctx.fillRect(midX, chartArea.top, chartArea.right - midX, midY - chartArea.top);

                // Bottom right quadrant
                ctx.fillStyle = window.chartColors.green;
                ctx.fillRect(midX, midY, chartArea.right - midX, chartArea.bottom - midY);

                // Bottom left quadrant
                ctx.fillStyle = window.chartColors.yellow;
                ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, midY, midX - chartArea.left, chartArea.bottom - midY);
              }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

### EDITADO

Un pequeño fallo que tenia pero que aun asi me sigue dando error era la posicion en la que añadia el require.js, al colocarlo el script por encima del chart.js deja de dar este error, pero me da otros tantos.

> Uncaught Error: Module name "core/core.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
>       at chart-test1.html:15

Me saca un ultimo error, esta vez con el require.js, este me muestra todo el codigo del archivo por lo que no se cual es el problema

Comment: Necesitas usar moment.js? En caso contrario prueba con la versión no bundle. Me da la idea de que la integración continua de Chart corre en node, donde sí está definido require, y liberaron un bundle defectuoso.

Comment: Pues nose si necesito o no el moment.js, esto probando distintas librerias para crear un bussines cycle clock y chart.js me parecia una buena opcion, pero viendo la cantidad de problemas que estoy teniendo probare con jqplot, o algun otro similar.

Comment: Prueba incluir la versión 2.5.0 no bundled desde el CDN, usando el link `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js` directo en tu código, sin descargarlo

Comment: No puedo usar script con enlaces, las librerias que use, js externos o css o cualquier archivo que use tiene que ser local.

Comment: Bueno, entonces cópiate esa versión, al menos si te da error será más explicativo que el que tienes ahora. Mirando el código, tiene las comprobaciones para correr como AMD, CommonJS o global, que sería tu caso.

Comment: De acuardo, lo probare en cuanto pueda, gracias